# How does WinFormsWebView work in IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples / WinForms /

Tags: openid-connect, identityserver3

I was able to copy the code for the WinFormsWebView from the WinForms sample in IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples and get it to work with the OIDC client.

However, I have no idea how it works and I don't want to put it in production without some basic knowledge.

How does the redirect uri: http://localhost/winforms.client work? I have to assume that there is some webserver present, but I can't find it.

I try to imitate it using the Winforms WebBrowser, but I can't get it to work.

Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no web server. Check the source code - it handles the navigation events of the browser to intercept the redirect to the redirect_uri.

The standard WinForms browser does not work - hence the custom subclass.

Comment: do you think something like this could be accomplished using Katana to create a web server?

Comment: why would you want a web server in a client side app?

Comment: Just curios if using the web server and winform web browser together would handle logging into IdentityServer instead of using the webview? It's just a theoretical question as I'm exploring all avenues